# Find element by partial id and text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium-webdriver

I have a page I'm testing using the selenium webdriver in C#. The page I'm testing is asp.net and uses a GridView. Within the grid, I need to find a label (`span` when rendered) by partial id (CSS Selector) since this could be anywhere in the grid (thus changing its id) but also by text because no more than one record will contain the word "Open" but the rest will contain the word "Closed". I need to include a partial ID because "Open" could appear anywhere else in the page in a span tag by itself. And, of course, the row that "Open" appears in in the grid will change its ID.

For example:

```
RecordID   SomeData   Status
1          Something1 Closed
2          Something2 Open    //find this row's status label
2          Something3 Closed
```

So far, I've had mild success with this

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Open')]"))
```

However, I do not want to rely on just text because, for example, there could a future help section or the "SomeData" column could contain anything including "Open"

So how can I `FindElement` by css selector for the partial id AND containing text "Open"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS selectors will not find containing text, only XPath will do that. You can use the XPath below,

```
//span[contains(@id,'somePartialId')][.='Open']
```

You didn't specify the partial ID to look for so you'll have to fill that in yourself. I changed the `contains()` to equals for the containing text because you are a lot more likely to find more than you bargained for with `contains()`. I would suggest that you always use equals if it is the entirety of the contained text and only use `contains()` if it's partial text.

Comment: That was it. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. And point noted on "contains".